# What does "Invalid AVC allowed in current policy" mean?

Tags: audit, selinux

I was looking into my selinux alert logfile and running over multiple entries labeled

```
**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***
```

I understand that this signals a problem (on *read* or *getattr* etc.) and I see which processes cause it, but what I do not understand is the label.

What is an *Invalid AVC*? And how can it be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [source for setroubleshoot](http://www.google.com/codesearch#wdK4IMJpRnk/framework/src/audit_data.py&q=%22Invalid%20AVC%20allowed%20in%20current%20policy%22&type=cs&l=957), you can see that this is where the error comes from:

```
self.why, bools = audit2why.analyze(str(self.scontext), str(self.tcontext), str(self.tclass), self.access)
    if self.why == audit2why.ALLOW:
        raise ValueError(_("%s \n**** Invalid AVC allowed in current policy ***\n") %  self.avc_record)
```

This code suggests that the message is prepended by `self.avc_record`. I don't have a lot of time right now, but as the method this code is in is called `derive_avc_info_from_audit_event`, I am guessing this means an audit.log message is not correctly parsed into AVC information.

The messages in the rest of the if ... else block suggest this could be caused by a bug in the policy.

Maybe you can post the complete error: I haven't seen this before and knowing the exact output might help shedding some light onto it.

Comment: Could be, I always updated the policy with suggestions from the plugins, now my sealerter doesn't work any longer so I'm pretty sure those automations have destroyed the policy. Maybe a reinstall of the system helps.